# How to configure mapping for text fields of type keyword in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have Category field and I need to configure mapping for it so I can use it only in term-level queries.

I have seen this approach:

```
"category": {
  "type": "text",
  "fields": {
    "keyword": {
      "type": "keyword"
    }
  }
}
```

and the other one is by using the analyzer "keyword":

```
"category": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "keyword"
}
```

My question is: what is the difference between the two mappings and how can I configure text field for term-level queries??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   "category": {
     "type": "text",
       "fields": {
         "keyword": {
           "type": "keyword"
         }
       }
    }
```

This definition is actually a  [Multifield](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) representation of category. In this you will have two different version of your field- One will be analyzed which can be directly accessed by `category` and another will be `Not-Analyzed` version which can be accesses by `category.keyword`.

The other definition you specified:

```
"category": {
    "type": "text",
    "analyzer": "keyword"
}
```

defines category as a text field whose analyzer is `keyword` i.e. category field will be stored as a `Not-Analyzed` field.

After the release of `5.0` version of Elasticsearch, all the fields with type `text` by default contains a not analyzed version as given [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. So for my case it is better to use the second mapping because I don't need to analyze categories so using term-level queries rather than full text queries is suitable for searching categories

Comment: Yeah.. you can use that or specify type as keyword as specified here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html